# Talend Tuniqrow Condition Specification

Tags: talend

I have been working on Talend lately, and I was wondering if I can specify Static conditions on the TUniqRow Component, as far as I know, In this component you select the columns needed, normally keys, then you can select the duplicates which is calculated based on the selection. Now, what I am looking for is, after choosing a column, I'd like to specify values in that column in which it if duplicates of those values occur it should go to the duplicates output. For example:
Say I have this list:

### ID  | Status

### 1   |1

### 1   |2

### 1   |3

### 1   |4

### 1   |5

### 1   |6

### 1   |5

### 1   |6

What I would like to specify is after choosing status, I specify the values 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

tFileInputDelimited ----->tUniqRow---(duplicates)-->tFilterRow---->tLogRow

input file is having both column ID & Status
In tUniqRow take duplicates flow based on STATUS column
than in tFilterRow, use equals operator on STATUS column and give value as "1" & "5" and select the logical operator as OR

hope this helps..